# Google restrict services to application-specific passwords

Tags: passwords, google, authentication

Is there no way to restrict services for Google's application-specific passwords? Those passwords have almost full access to your account. It seems like design flaw. Eg. if I generate generate a password for a google reader app which doesn't support OAuth, I want to limit that password to the Google Reader service and not give it access to my mail.

In fact, application specific passwords could have been implemented very similar to OAuth tokens. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have recently wondered the same. I guess that the sheer length of application specific passwords makes them somewhat safe – but having too many of them really defeats the purpose of two-factor auth it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got an idea that might help. Create another Google account and only use that one for Reader. Since you are only going to use it for Reader, you might not even care to use 2-factor auth but it should not matter either way now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say so, but there is no way to do what you are asking for.

I would like to say that, Application specific password is only for mobile apps where the SMS cannot be generated/is not supported.

So, if you use application specific password to log on to Google Reader App, the App must be so deigned that you cannot open your GMail e-mails within the app.